# Окрашивание ячеек таблицы случайным цветом с помощью генератора случайных чисел

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа, math

Как окрасить ячейки таблицы случайным цветом с помощью генератора случайных чисел Math.random()?

Comment: Укажите тег языка в вопросе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
var g = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);

document.body.bgColor = 'RGB(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
```

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так:

```
var hex = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
console.log(hex); // #f69608
```